# Pass data between three activities in Xamarin (scheme)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity

My problem was presented at picture below:
[image: Scheme]
From "Browse files from folder" activity I'm sending data with:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Downloads));
intent.PutExtra("downloads", fileWithHashcode);
StartActivity(intent);
```

In "Downloads list" activity I'm getting data with:

```
string myData= Intent.GetStringExtra("downloads") ?? string.Empty;
```

processing and adding results to list. But I have problems with remembering this downloads list. I tried with `OnSaveInstanceState` - `OnRestoreInstanceState`. Not works.

**Each position in downloads list will be started in separate thread with started service.** It's a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution :

When you press a button to do download a file, you could store the download message in database. Every time when you get into `DownLoadList` activity, you could restore the download message from your database and refresh this activity to show the latest download list.

Comment: For example this database?? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/

Comment: @DamianOS.MP5,  this database could satisfy your need.

Comment: Not yet. For now I have more important problem but I think that database is a good solution and I apply this :) Thanks for answer.